# What does this symbol "~" mean in the web.config appsetting

Tags: path, relative-path

```
 <add key="ImageStore" value="~/UserMedia" />
```

I have this variable specified and up to now it was working. It just stopped for some reason two days ago.  "UserMedia" is a virtual directory in the root of the website, which is mapped to "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\UserMedia" but when the page gets called, I get the path relative to the directory of the .asp page instead.

Comment: Take a look at this SuperUser question, it's your same question. http://superuser.com/questions/211355/what-does-the-mean-in-a-file-path

Comment: I know my problem. When reading the key as this  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ImageStore"), I lose the tilde character. Not sure why. It only happens now. It's been working fine. No change in code.

Comment: I figured out my problem. Silly me! Having an external config file that has the same key and it keeps reading from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tilde character "~" generally means "Root Directory" in .NET web type projects, and usually refers to the root of the website.

So, "~/UserMedia", is likely part of a file path.